# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined, what to do?

Tags: properties, undefined, innerhtml, typeerror

This is my js code, and after running it with the project, i get the error saying that
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined".

What to do?

```
<code>
$(document).ready(function() {
var eventFired = function ( type ) {
    var n = $('#demo_info')[0];
    n.innerHTML += '<div>'+type+' event - '+new Date().getTime()+'</div>';
    n.scrollTop = n.scrollHeight;      
};

$('#example')
    .on( 'order.dt',  function () { eventFired( 'Order' ); } )
    .on( 'search.dt', function () { eventFired( 'Search' ); } )
    .on( 'page.dt',   function () { eventFired( 'Page' ); } )
    .dataTable();
} );
</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing plain JS with jQuery. `$('#demo_info')` returns a jQuery object that does not have `innerHtml` defined on it. What has `innerHtml` defined on it is an element reference returned by `document.getElementById()` or other similar functions that are built into JS.

Since you're using jQuery, just use its `html()` method instead, which internally calls `innerHtml` anyway. This should do the trick:

```
var old_html = n.html();
var new_html = '<div>' + type + ' event - ' + new Date().getTime() + '</div>';
n.html(old_html + new_html);
```

Hope this helps.